# Replace a "tag" with a Dictionary value which key is the tag

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

Let's say I have a Dictionary of the following form:

```
"NUM" : "1"
"TEXT" : "abc"
```

and a string like: `"This pair contains {NUM} and {TEXT}"`,

**How can I replace `{NUM}` and `{TEXT}` with the appropriate values from my Dictionary?**

Here's the code I have for now:

```cs
Regex.Replace(myString, // "This pair contains {NUM} and {TEXT}"
    @"{([\w\s]*)}", // Gets any word or space character between braces
    myDictionary[@"$1"]) // Does not work, it literally searches for "$1" instead of the match
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use match evaluator instead.

Regex

```
@"{([\w\s]*)}"
```

Code

```
var result = Regex.Replace(myString, // "This pair contains {NUM} and {TEXT}"
    @"{([\w\s]*)}", // Gets any word or space character between braces
    m => myDictionary.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value)
         ? myDictionary[m.Groups[1].Value]  // to be safe do the checking
         : string.Empty);
```

Output

```
This pair contains 1 and abc
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/287joW)